# AWS Serverless Excel download

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to download an Excel file by using below Lambda function code (ASP .Net Core 3.1) deployed in AWS. But I am getting file corrupted issue.

**ReportController.cs:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
   Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
   Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
   worksheet.Zoom = 80;
   Style titleheaderStyle = worksheet.Workbook.CreateStyle();
   titleheaderStyle.Font.Name = "Calibri";
   titleheaderStyle.Font.Size = 13;
   titleheaderStyle.Font.IsBold = true;
   titleheaderStyle.Font.IsItalic = true;
   titleheaderStyle.HorizontalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Left;
   titleheaderStyle.VerticalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Top;
   worksheet.Cells[0, 0].PutValue("Report");
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   workbook.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
   byte[] b1 = ms.ToArray();
   ms.Flush();
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testfile1.xlsx");
   Response.Body.WriteAsync(b1);
   return Ok();
}
```

**LambdaEntryPoint.cs:**

```
protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
   RegisterResponseContentEncodingForContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", ResponseContentEncoding.Base64);
   builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

We have updated Binary Media Type as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" in AWS API Gateway and set Content handling to Convert to binary (CONVERT_TO_BINARY) in GET integration response and also updated 200 status method response with "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" Content-Type. How to resolve the above issue?

**Update:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
   Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
   Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
   worksheet.Zoom = 80;
   Style titleheaderStyle = worksheet.Workbook.CreateStyle();
   titleheaderStyle.Font.Name = "Calibri";
   titleheaderStyle.Font.Size = 13;
   titleheaderStyle.Font.IsBold = true;
   titleheaderStyle.Font.IsItalic = true;
   titleheaderStyle.HorizontalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Left;
   titleheaderStyle.VerticalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Top;
   worksheet.Cells[0, 0].PutValue("Report");
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   workbook.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
   byte[] b1 = ms.ToArray();
   ms.Flush();
   return new FileContentResult(b1, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
   {
      FileDownloadName = "testfile1.xlsx"
   };
}
```

Comment: Why are you interacting directly with the response in the controller? Why not return a file result?

Comment: @mason, I have tried with file result return type. No luck.

Comment: You haven't shown your attempt with the file result return type.

Comment: @mason, I have updated my code with file result return type.

Answer (score 0):

In your LambdaEntryPoint class try registering the content type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` to be base64 encoding by calling the `RegisterResponseContentEncodingForContentEncoding` method.

Comment: I have already registered content type as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" in LambdaEntryPoint class and tried that option as well. Please check my above code.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to register/whitelist Binary Media Types on the **AWS Console** at **API Gateway -> Settings** menu
or
in the **CloudFormation template** as below:

```
"Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreApi": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
      "Properties": {
        "StageName": "Prod",
        "BinaryMediaTypes": [
          "*~1*"
        ]
      }
    }
```